# AWS Cloudformation - How to attach vpc link / NLB to method in api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

This has been such a pain in the backend to waste hours and still unable to get one line of AWS CloudFormation syntax clear.

If the AWS guys can write their documentation slightly better - just pay a little bit more attention to it - it would make like easier for the developers.

I am trying to use CloudFormation to deploy API Gateway with VPC Link and NLB. The Goal is to proxy pass all requests to the NLB:

```
  ApiProxyMethod: 
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiProxyResource
      # AuthorizationScopes: # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-authorizationscopes
      AuthorizationType: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      AuthorizerId: !Ref ApiAuthorizer
      HttpMethod: ANY
      OperationName: "ProxyAllRequests"
      Integration: 
        ConnectionType: VPC_LINK
        ConnectionId: !Ref ApiGatewayVpcLink
        IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
        PassthroughBehavior: String
        Type: "VPC_LINK" # Member must satisfy enum value set: [HTTP, AWS_PROXY, HTTP_PROXY, AWS] 
        Uri: "http://NLB-myapp-internal-beta-12345.elb.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/{proxy}"
```

However, this fails and it complains about wrong `Type` value: `Member must satisfy enum value set: [HTTP, AWS_PROXY, HTTP_PROXY, AWS]`

Now, which one of them is for VPC_Link / NLB?

They could have listed these values in the documentation of `AWS::ApiGateway::Method Integration`, but they choose not to.

Comment: This is from the docs: An HTTP or HTTP proxy integration with a `connectionType` of VPC_LINK is referred to as a private integration and uses a VpcLink to connect API Gateway to a network load balancer of a VPC. And also: For a private HTTP integration, the URI is not used for routing.

Comment: @MarkoE  Where is this documented? I was so frustrated that I didn't find this.

Comment: Second one is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_PutIntegration.html#apigw-PutIntegration-request-uri. The first one is referred in response syntax: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_PutIntegration.html#apigw-PutIntegration-response-type.

Answer (score 5):

In order to proxy pass all requests to the NLB, you need to specify the `Type` field as `HTTP_PROXY`

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_Integration.html#apigw-Type-Integration-connectionType) you can find more useful documentation about integration parameters

```
  ApiProxyMethod: 
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties: 
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiProxyResource
      AuthorizationType: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
      AuthorizerId: !Ref ApiAuthorizer
      HttpMethod: ANY
      OperationName: "ProxyAllRequests"
      Integration: 
        ConnectionType: VPC_LINK
        ConnectionId: !Ref ApiGatewayVpcLink
        IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
        PassthroughBehavior: String
        Type: HTTP_PROXY
        Uri: "http://NLB-myapp-internal-beta-12345.elb.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/{proxy}"
```